# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hbase.properties' in string value "file://${hbase.properties}"

Tags: java, xml, hbase, spring-data

I am having some trouble and can't figure out why. I keep getting:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hbase.properties' in string value "file://${hbase.properties}"
```

in my context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">


    <context:property-placeholder location="hbase.properties"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hyatt.rtap.viewer"/>

    <hdp:configuration id="hadoopConfiguration">
        fs.defaultFS=hdfs://localhost:8080
    </hdp:configuration>


    <hdp:hbase-configuration configuration-ref="hadoopConfiguration"  zk-quorum="${hbase.zk.host}" zk-port="${hbase.zk.port}"/>




</beans>
```

My hbase.properties is as follows:

```
hbase.zk.host=sandbox.hortonworks.com
hbase.zk.port=2181
```

I can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Please post content of hbase.properties

Comment: It is there. Check bottom of post